# My laptop is plugged in, charging but power is not increasing

Tags: laptop, battery

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 14 R.

Yesterday I got the notification to plug the laptop into power source when the charge became low at 13%, so I plugged it to the power source and it showed charging.

But since then the battery power % is not increasing, it is still staying at the same 13%. At the same time it is showing plugged in and charging when I hover over the battery symbol. The battery meter shows that the battery is performing normally.

I did the hard reset by pressing the power button for 30 seconds by removing the battery and charger.  Still no change. Any help!

PS: The battery and charger are genuine Dell products. This is my second genueine Dell battery I bought 6 months ago

Comment: Time for a new battery?

Comment: How old is your battery?

Comment: This is my second genueine Dell battery I bought 6 months ago FYI!

Comment: I would try another Dell power brick.

Comment: @Moab I also tried with same Dell charger of my brother's lap.

Comment: Is this a problem with the mother board? Anyway I'm going to contact Dell support

Comment: It could be a motherboard issue.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That was a mother board issue. I don't know the exact reason. Any way as I told, I contacted the Dell service and they replaced the mother board of my laptop. Now my lap is working fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my laptop issue is now resolved, I'm posting answer myself. I contacted Dell service, after some phone calls as it was hard to understand what the real issue was and there was no error codes showed in the Dell system diagnostics, they sent a technician to check the system. The technician checked the system by inserting a same battery as mine and it also shown the same issue. He also checked my battery by inserting into another system and my battery charged. From this they came to the conclusion that the issue is with the mother board. Then he registered the complaint and ordered a mother board and after two days they came with a new mother board and replaced.

Now my laptop is working fine. I'm now getting a battery backup of up to 4 and a half hours.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already tried reseating the battery/removing it for 60s+, it may be time for a new battery.

You can also try some 3rd party tools to test:

- http://batterycare.bkspot.com/en/index.html
- http://www.passmark.com/products/batmon.htm

Answer (score -1):

Or the charger does not give enough ampers to your battery! Before spending money on a new battery, try a similar charger with same output voltage and similar ampers, max +10% more ampers.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  If you wish to leave a comment to other people's questions you must first earn reputation in order to do so.

Comment: @user I tried! No difference at all