# Dell Inspiron 3420, Charger Plugged in , Charging, But Battery Percentage not going up

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I got a problem from last few days, searched every where for solution but all in vain.

**Description:**
I have DEll Inspiron 3420. When I plug in Charger,it shows charging but Battery level remains at the point on which the charger is plugged. It does not go up.
It does not show any charger or battery related message. Everything is normal.

**What I Have Tried So Far**

1. Removed the battery, checked laptop on charger only, and its working fine.
2. Checked the battery on another system and its charging in that system properly, mean that battery is fine.
3. Checked my system on another charger[swapped with my friend having same system], but problem remains the same, mean its not the charger issue.
4. After reading on several blogs, tried the battery removal and driver uninstall trick, but its not working.
5. Removed battery, pressed power key for about a minute, no result.
6. Checked internal hardware, i.e socket, its all good, checked on checking meter, all pins are working good.
7. Check main board, where the charging sockets is connected to main board via connectors, its all good. Nothing is misshaped, burnt, or overheated. No bad smell even.
8. Plugged battery from another system, that too is having the same issue in my system.
9. Updated BIOS from Dell Website, Still Not Working

What could be the reason? Kindly someone help me.

Comment: Borrow another battery and use that battery in your machine. Does that battery take the charge? It sounds like the battery port/jack is bust

Comment: Tried that too Bro. Not Working.
From Jack you mean the pins which get connected to battery when its plugged? they are fine

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the pins which connects the battery to the computer. Also, can you confirm that the battery isn't charging? I know it's not showing you but, if you let it run flat, charge it for 1 hour, does it have any power?

Comment: Yesterday my battery was at 27% , i charged it for more than 90 minutes it was still at 27%. And when i unplugged the charger, Percentage started to come down normally.
Those pins are also good as i checked that on main board too.

Comment: This post, which may be a duplicate could help - [My laptop is plugged in, charging but power is not increasing](http://superuser.com/questions/922829/my-laptop-is-plugged-in-charging-but-power-is-not-increasing)

Comment: Whether BIOS has something to do with Charging?
BIOS show that battery charging status is IDLE